# Should I return user data in an authentication endpoint using JWT?

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt, api-design

I implement an auth endpoint which takes an email and password and returns a JWT token.
Inside the JWT there is a payload containing the user ID.
Does it matter from a REST/JWT standards perspective which of these approaches I take?

1. return the token and let the client request the `/users/user_id` resource on a callback with the decoded user_id and the token
2. return the entire user object with the token from the `/auth` endpoint for the convenience of the client.

(my question is implementation/library agnostic and about the api-design pattern)

Comment: Question: If the user doesn't already know its own user ID, then how can it retrieve it later after authentication?  To your direct question, if there is a lot of user metadata, then yes maybe that should be accessed at a different REST endpoint.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on your question @Tim-Biegeleisen; but the JWT will always return the user ID, the user will always have their credentials for login so they can log in again if the token is gone. The ID can always be decoded from the token. The question is more if there's any reason not to follow the convenience of putting user data on the `auth` endpoint other than that it's not exactly as RESTful as having the `GET` `users/user_id` be the single resource for the user data...

Comment: If you're talking about _just_ a user ID alone, then return it with the auth call.  If there are many points of user metadata, then I suggest creating a separate endpoint for that (which sits behind authentication).

Comment: Thanks for this, but since they will need to have valid credentials to get the auth endpoint to return, what additional security would only returning the other data through the enpoint that requires the token provide @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: It's not a security thing, it's a microservice separation of concerns thing.  The auth endpoint should be there for authentication only.  Other types of data should have their own endpoints.  But again if we're only talking about the user ID, it's fine to return after authenticating.

Comment: thanks, that was what I was driving at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Here is a link to a more thorough discussion and answer to this question on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/419384)**

To summarize the discussion there; if the API is internally used then it matters less, if you are providing an external API with multiple consumers it matters more. There is no discussion of any security risks with either approach.